# iPhone : Leave page turning API low PDF Quality

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using Leave API but the problem is this API render pdf files low quality is there any possible way to solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: I always considered the leaves API very high quality.  And besides, it's Quartz Core that's rendering the pages. Leaves calculates the size of the screen and pages for animation purposes and caches the pages in the background.

Comment: so what is the solution to  fix this ?

Comment: Higher quality media.  It is no fault of quartz if the initial PDF is of low quality, as Tom Brow's Example paper is.

Comment: It's not just text.  It's probably a series of pictures (which is why PDF's are notoriously hard to edit).  Tom's example paper is not a very high quality PDF compared to, say, an IRS tax form.  Try downloading one of those and replacing it with the example.

Comment: please change the colors in that sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This new API by Vortec4800 fixed low quality and retina support , download and use it ;)

https://github.com/Vortec4800/leaves